# Create space on right side of plot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

It is hard to see the last datapoint on the chart when it is right next to the y-axis. I would like to create some space between my last data point and the right y-axis. Any idea how to create this space?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime as dt 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##Get stock price data
ticker = '^GSPC, AAPL'

#get data from YFinance
df = yf.download(ticker, period = "max" , interval = "1d")['Adj Close']

#Convert the 'Date' Index to 'Date' Column
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df['GSPCpctchange'] = (df['^GSPC'] / df['^GSPC'].shift(1))-1
df['AAPLpctchange'] = (df['AAPL'] / df['AAPL'].shift(1))-1

df['10_percent_R'] = df['GSPCpctchange'].rolling(10).corr(df['AAPLpctchange'])
df['10_price_R'] = df['^GSPC'].rolling(10).corr(df['AAPL'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
# Assign this as index
df.set_index(['Date'], inplace=True)

#Chart S&P500 and AAPL 10D R on one chart
plt.style.use('classic')
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,9))

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

fig.suptitle('S&P500 10D Correlation with AAPL', fontsize=16)

ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('S&P500', color="blue")
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor="blue")
ax1.plot(df.loc['2019-01-01':'2021-02-27','^GSPC'], linewidth=3, color="blue")

ax2.set_ylabel('10D AAPL Correlation', color="navy")  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor="navy")
ax2.plot(df.loc['2019-01-01':'2021-02-27','10_percent_R'], color="orange")
ax2.plot(df.loc['2019-01-01':'2021-02-27','10_price_R'], color="navy")

ax1.grid()
plt.legend(['Percent R','Price R'], loc="upper left")
```

[image: AAPL]

Comment: Does `ax2.margins(x=0.05)` work for you? (to be added after the plotting functions.)

Comment: Hello JohanC, I did not get this to work, however, ffdoctor's response did work below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```py
ax1.set_xlim(['2019-01-01', '2021-03-01'])
```